# How to secure apis with ResourceServer implementation with multiple resource ids?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a requirement where I need to secure different set of apis in my application with different tokens obtained by different resource server.

/api/user/** -> Apis should be authenticated with token(T1), obtained from provider RS1
/api/admin/** -> Apis should be authenticated with token(T2), obtained from provider RS2

T1 should not be able to access /api/admin/** and
T2 should not be able to access /api/user/**

Both - RS1 and RS2 issue JWTs.

How is this possible, using Spring's Resource server implementation? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to say that the different tokens are obtained from different authorization servers.

In this case you can look into multi-tenant applications.

One way to differentiate tenants is by the issuer claim. For this you can use a `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver` or `JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver`.

```java
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver = 
            new JwtIssuerReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver(
                    "https://idp.example.org/issuerOne",
                    "https://idp.example.org/issuerTwo");

    http
            .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)
            );
    return http.build();
}
```

Here are some more resources to help you get started:

- Multi-tenancy section in the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html)
- A [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/multi-tenancy) in the spring-security GitHub repository
- [Multi-tenancy OAuth with Spring Security 5.2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ke13w8nab-k) talk from SpringOne 2019